# GCC Error -mgeneral-regs-only

Tags: linux, gcc

Скачал драйвер [Intel® Network Adapter Driver for PCI-E* Gigabit Network Connections under Linux*](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817). Следую инструкции по установке. После выполнения команды `make install`, получаю ошибку:

> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ´-mgeneral-regs-only´

Comment: Где сборка идёт? Этот ключ валиден только для архитектуры AArch64.

Comment: @PinkTux Tegra-Ubuntu 3.10.67, aarch64

Comment: @Insider: какая версия gcc?

Comment: @МАН69К 4.8.4-2ubuntu1-14.04.3

Comment: Проверяйте `gcc -dumpmachine`, `gcc -v`.  что там насчёт `64` встретится.

Comment: @PinkTux `gcc -dumpmachine` - выдает `arm-linux-gnueabihf`. `gcc -v` - с 64 ничего не встречается.

Comment: @PinkTux не могли бы вы помощь до конца?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации по GCC
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ `-mgeneral-regs-only` появляется только в GCC 4.8.5, исходя из этого, достаточно обновить GCC до указанной версии или выше.